# How to fix "The name 'string' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

Im in proccess of learning c#. I made this code but for some reasons it shows that "NameSurnameGrade(this is my string)" doesnt exist.

This is just for me to be able to understand the code better.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BASE
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string NameSurnameGrade(string name, string surname, int grade)
        {
            string details = string.Format("Name : {0}, Lastname {1}, Grade {2}", name, surname, grade);
            return details;
        }
        public static void NameSurnameGrade2()
        {
            string name = "John";
            string surname = "Doe";
            int grade = 35;
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Lastname: {1}, Grade: {2}", name, surname, grade);
        }
    }

        class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student a = new Student();
            string result = a.NameSurnameGrade("Jack", "Park", 10);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();

            NameSurnameGrade2();
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } 
    }
```

I have implemented 2 methods in this and ony this one wont work. is it maybe because of this code?
I expect it to execute without errors, this is one a prat of code btw, but tis shows that NameSurnameGrade2 does not exist

Comment: Can't reproduce. https://ideone.com/U00nL6

Comment: Don't paraphrase compiler errors. Show your actual code and the actual error.

Comment: it sounds like you implemented the 2 methods in different classes

Comment: I did implemented 2 methods and this one wont work

Comment: "I did implemented 2 methods" we can see that, we just don't know which are the 2 methods and where you implemented them? 2 different `NameSurnameGrade2` methods? one without and one with parameters? like `public static void NameSurnameGrade2(string stuff)` ??

Comment: Ill just post the whole code

Comment: Mate, see my 1st comment from above: "it sounds like you implemented the 2 methods in different classes". Did you actually even read it? you need to use the class name of the class `Student.NameSurnameGrade2()`. because it is static

Comment: Sorry am super new to this and not experienced at all, sorry

Comment: don't worry, welcome to StackOverflow. Read and duplicate and it should solve your problem. In future please read the comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void NameSurnameGrade2()
```

is in the wrong class. move the function to class `Program`

Furthermore `class Program` needs to be `public`

Another possiblity would be to change the function to  `public void NameSurnameGrade2()` and acces it with `a.NameSurenameGrade2();`

Comment: Thank oyu mate, that works as well

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, Lastname: {1}, Grade: {2}", name, surname, grade));
```

instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Lastname: {1}, Grade: {2}", name, surname, grade);
```

Comment: 1) how is this supposed to solve the problem? 2)  `WriteLine` support the formatting of strings. `string.Format` is not necessary

Comment: man yea, I did that, wont work

Comment: OK - did not know that WriteLine supports formatting. I tried the code provided, it works for me.